# Minimum Size of DFA

Tags: automata

I'm confused about the following DFA problem:

*Let L denote the set of all strings in $\{a, b\}^∗$ that contain abb or aab as a substring. Show that any DFA that decides L must have at least five states.*

I think L can be decided in a 4 state DFA as follows:

q0 (start state): 
 
a -> q1 
b -> q0

q1: 
a,b -> q2

q2: 
b -> q3
a -> q0

q3 (accept state)
a,b -> q3

Note: q3 is the only accept state
Why does this DFA not decide L?

Comment: It looks like your DFA does not accept $aaab$, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Rolf Hoyer** noted in the comments, your DFA does not accept $aaab$, which is in $L$. The problem is that after you’ve read $a$, it really does make a different whether the next input is an $a$ or a $b$: if it’s an $a$, you can read any number of $a$s and still be two-thirds of the way to having the substring $aab$, but if it’s a $b$, then another $a$ puts you back at only one-third of the way to an acceptable substring.

The easiest argument to show that at least five states are needed uses the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem): show that the strings $a$, $b$, $aa$, $ab$, and $aab$ all have distinguishing extensions and therefore must correspond to different states.